# No entiendo este script

Tags: javascript, jquery

No entiendo muy bien que valor llega a obtener este script `$( this ).parent().get( 0 ).tagName;`. Además, con el => `document.createTextNode( parentTag + " > "` no entiendo mucho.

```js
 $( "*", document.body ).each(function() {
      var parentTag = $( this ).parent().get( 0 ).tagName;
      $( this ).prepend( document.createTextNode( parentTag + " > " ) );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>div,
      <span>span, </span>
      <b>b </b>
    </div>
     
    <p>p,
      <span>span,
        <em>em </em>
      </span>
    </p>
     
    <div>div,
      <strong>strong,
        <span>span, </span>
        <em>em,
          <b>b, </b>
        </em>
      </strong>
      <b>b </b>
    </div>
```

**Resultado**

- BODY > div, DIV > span, DIV > b
- BODY > p, P > span, SPAN > em
- BODY > div, DIV > strong, STRONG > span, STRONG > em, EM > b, DIV > b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**te explico:**
supongo que su funcionalidad es para crear `Breadcrumbs`

```
   // seleccionamos todo los elementos dentro del document body y hacemos un loop foreach para cada elemento
$( "*", document.body ).each(function() {
  // seleccionamos solo al padre del elemento y obtenemos su tag " p div h1 etc..";
  var parentTag = $( this ).parent().get( 0 ).tagName;
  // el elemento seleccionado creamos un "createTextNode = innerHTML" son casi lo mismo
  // y le agregamos al principio del tag un texto con el nombre del padre + un ">"
  $( this ).prepend( document.createTextNode( parentTag + " > " ) );
});
```

> nota no es del todo eficiente porque le agregara a todos los elementos asi sea un tag `script`